# How to establish database connection within a Nest.js e2e test

Tags: node.js, testing, nestjs, azure-cosmosdb, e2e-testing

I'm having an issue connecting to CosmosDB within a Nest.js e2e test.
I've been following the Nest.js documentation for creating e2e tests but it doesn't contain any documentation on connecting to a test database. Some of the articles I found (both on SO, and numerous other websites) stated that I should just initialize the database as I would within a regular module, but inside of the testing module, but it didn't work for me.

Module for CosmosDB that I'm using is [@nestjs/azure-database](https://github.com/nestjs/azure-database).

I tried to initialize the AzureCosmosDbModule through the imports of the testing module as mentioned above but without any success.

Below is a snippet of what I tried. (I changed the actual name of the controller, module, etc. to a random "cats" one)

Environment variable loading is set up correctly, as it works outside of the tests.

```
describe('CatsController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          validationSchema: schema,
          isGlobal: true,
        }),
        AzureCosmosDbModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [ConfigModule],
          useFactory: async (cfg: ConfigService) => ({
            endpoint: cfg.get<string>('AZURE_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT'),
            dbName: cfg.get<string>('AZURE_COSMOS_DB_TEST_NAME'),
            key: cfg.get<string>('AZURE_COSMOS_DB_KEY'),
          }),
          inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
        CatsModule,
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    app.setGlobalPrefix('api');

    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

**Error message I get after running e2e test.**

```
[Nest] 2355  - 08/25/2022, 11:27:33 AM   ERROR [AzureCosmosDbModule] Unable to connect to the cosmos db database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 2355  - 08/25/2022, 11:27:36 AM   ERROR [AzureCosmosDbModule] Unable to connect to the cosmos db database. Retrying (2)...
```

Comment: Have you validated the connection string and the key?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, the env variables (endpoint, dbName, and key) are correct

Comment: If you console.log the return value of the factory function, does it work?

Comment: @dan-ros yeah, console logging the factory function works